# O365 Graph API, GET /groups return null entities

Tags: odata, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

i'm trying develop an app that integrate with O365 Groups, for that i need all the info i can get. using the Graph API Explorer when i call "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/"
i get answer like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups/$entity",
    "id": "8143b56b-a4bb-43ef-8b17-a747b1cacec1",
    "createdDateTime": "2016-02-23T11:03:33Z",
    "description": "asd asd asd ",
    "displayName": "Test Group",
    "groupTypes": [
        "Unified"
    ],
    "mail": "testgroup@fastgroup.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mailEnabled": true,
    "mailNickname": "testgroup",
    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
    "proxyAddresses": [
        "SMTP:testgroup@fastgroup.onmicrosoft.com"
    ],
    "renewedDateTime": "2016-02-23T11:03:33Z",
    "securityEnabled": false,
    "visibility": "Public"
}
```

but once i'm calling the same rest function from my app i get most of the entities as null, like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups/$entity",
    "id": "8143b56b-a4bb-43ef-8b17-a747b1cacec1",
    "createdDateTime": null,
    "description": null,
    "displayName": "Test Group",
    "groupTypes": [],
    "mail": null,
    "mailEnabled": null,
    "mailNickname": null,
    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
    "proxyAddresses": [],
    "renewedDateTime": null,
    "securityEnabled": null,
    "visibility": null
}
```

can someone please tell me what i'm missing?

Access token scopes in my app: Group.Read.All User.Read.

Thanks!

Comment: This is indeed a little strange, given the permissions that your app is using.  Can you provide some more details like the client-request-id and the timestamp for the call please (you should be able to see this through a fiddler trace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently we only return the basic properties of the group with the group.read.all permission. We will be changing that in the future to return all properties (as long as the signed-in user has permissions to read the group property information).

For now you will need to use group.readwrite.all to get the full properties of the group.

I'll update this answer once we make the update.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. BTW i needed to remove the app from O365 and connect it again to get the new permissions. change in azure ad is not enough.

Comment: You can revoke the app and re-consent.  Will that work for you?  You can revoke here https://portal.office.com/account/#apps

Comment: Is this still the case in 2021 ?